# Canva Domain to Google Workspace

Tags: dns, google-workspace

I tried creating a domain on google but it wouldn't allow me to do so, so I went and purchased the domain through canva which is where my website is hosted. Now I am trying to create a business email through google again but it will not allow me to add the domain details from Canva. It still says my domain is in use but won't allow me to add details. How can I connect the two?

I've tried getting help through google support but there are no humans to explain this to, the automated communication does not help.